# How can I convert a date to a string without using DateFormatter?

Tags: swift

How can I convert Date.now to a string without using DateFormatter?

Comment: Why? Usually a `DateFormatter` is preferred. Why do you need that? What should be the output?

Comment: When asking a question "how to achieve X without using Y" where Y is an appropriate method for the task and is part of the language/standard library, you should explain why is Y not suitable for your goals. Otherwise you're highly unlikely to receive a high-quality answer, since anyone trying to answer your question will be in the dark trying to figure out your requirements.

Comment: That's true **Dávid Pastor**, and when your effort doesn't meet the criteria of the asker... it demotes your answer. That's to me to not, ever, respond such kind of question.

Comment: @Larme Because I was trying to format a date in a SwiftUI view and had declared a DateFormatter, but when I tried to set the dateStyle property on the formatter I got a vague error about separating statements with ';'. I didn't realize that anything beyond declarations has to be in a function body and couldn't figure out how to make it work so I was looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new `.formatted()` syntax:

```
Date.now.formatted()
Date.now.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could:

```swift
let date = Date()
let dateString = date.formatted()
print("Today is \(dateString), also work with \(date) directly.")
```

But you miss the **control** to *format* the date ;-)

EDIT: Sorry, I responded at the same time as **@jrturton**